# I am unable to config JDK and Maven in Jenkins 2.7.2

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have already used older version where I can see JDK or Maven path but not in Jenkins 2.7.2 .
I tried to include inside Environmental variable but it still my build is showing failure .
I have all updated plugin installed in Jenkins

[Below is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjt0w.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's a new link **Global Tool Configuration** on the **Manage Jenkins** page.

Comment: I tried that too .
But am still unable to create a maven project in It